# utf-8 encoding issues (\udbff, \udc13, \udc02, \udc00, \udc06) where the escape surrogates solution doesn't work

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, utf

Having issues with encoding (\udbff, \udc13, \udc02, \udc00,  \udc06). I've tried looking at this online and tried the following

```
 print('\udc13'.encode('utf8','surrogateescape'))
```

This results in the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc13' in position 0: surrogates not allowed

Any suggestions on how I can avoid this range. I keep finding new ones so escaping each one with regex doesn't seem like a sustainable solution.

Comment: Can't you use `'ignore'` or `'replace'`? [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). I mean if you think of escaping things, using replace or some other feature might be better?

Comment: @Torxed I tried that. Doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: `'\udc13'.encode('utf8','backslashreplace')` for instance, should keep the character *as-is* and simply escape it with an additional backslash. You're telling me, that doesn't work?

Comment: well I apply it to all values in a column. It works if I run it as a standalone example on the terminal. I apply it to the column the following way(cdf here is the column):   `cDF.apply(lambda x: x.encode(encoding="utf-8",errors='backslashreplace'))`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by replacing 'surrogateescape' with 'backslashreplace'.

Answer (score -1):

I had to escape the full range `u"([\udc00-\udc69])|"` to get ride of it in the end. I guess I should probably expand it to udcff or something to make it more complete!

Comment: Surrogates range from U+D800 to U+DFFF.  U+D800 to U+DBFF are "high" surrogates and U+DC00 to U+DFFF are "low" surrogates.  They are used to encode Unicode codepoints above U+FFFF in UTF-16.  They should normally only appear as a pair of of them in high/low order in UTF-16-*encoded* data.  Why do you have them in your Unicode strings?

Comment: good question! I've never come across surrogates before! I am just trying to clean up some really messy data from third party sources and they have that in their strings. Is the -1 because of the editing? :/ why is this question a bad question?

Comment: I don’t know. I guess this answer doesn’t completely answer the question. It looks like you use a regular expression but the code isn’t complete or explained. The question doesn’t have an [mcve]. The real problem might be how the data was read in the first place.